# PHP JQuery document ready adding an IF statement breaks .show( )

Tags: php, jquery, if-statement, document-ready

The following code is placed in the (document).ready function and works to display the order form properly:

```
    <?php   if (isset($_POST['preview-order'])) {    //IF PREVIEW FORM  ?>
            $("#cam-order-preview").show('slow');
    <?php   } else {                                //ELSE ORDER FORM  ?>               
        if (lastAreaVisible != "") { 
            $("#<?php echo $_SESSION['last_area_visible'];?>").css("visibility", "visible");
            $("#<?php echo $_SESSION['last_area_visible'];?>").css("position", "relative");
            $("#<?php echo $_SESSION['last_area_visible'];?>").css("display", "block");
            $("#<?php echo $_SESSION['last_area_visible'];?>").show('slow');            
        } 
            $("#cam-order-form").show('slow');
            $("#cam-order-nav").show('slow');                   
            $("#order-comment-box").show('slow');
```

The problem is if the 'last_area_visible' value is set, I want to conditionally hide the other sections so I add an else statement like so but the else statement causes the entire form to break and nothing to be displayed as if the jquery stopped parsing.

```
<?php   if (isset($_POST['preview-order'])) {   //IF PREVIEW FORM   ?>
                $("#cam-order-preview").show('slow');
        <?php   } else     {                                //ELSE ORDER FORM   ?>              
if (lastAreaVisible != "") { 
 $("#<?php echo $_SESSION['last_area_visible'];?>").css("visibility", "visible");
 $("#<?php echo $_SESSION['last_area_visible'];?>").css("position", "relative");
 $("#<?php echo $_SESSION['last_area_visible'];?>").css("display", "block");
 $("#<?php echo $_SESSION['last_area_visible'];?>").show('slow');           
} else { 
 $("#cam-order-form").show('slow');
 $("#cam-order-nav").show('slow');                  
 $("#order-comment-box").show('slow');
}
```

Any insight? THe top code works and displays all the sections, I just want to hide the bottom three but jquery doesn't like it for some strange reason.

Comment: What is the error you are getting in the browser console?

Comment: Also, is it possible to paste this section of code from page source, so that we can see what PHP is giving out?

Comment: Using Opera, there are only CSS errors in console all from jquery-ui.css nothing related to JS at all.
 HTML style attribute and DOM style property for property zoom

Comment: Are you able to see `last_area_visible` field?

Comment: Here is the complete  relevant section of document.ready 
 http://jsfiddle.net/y59QV/

Comment: And when the problem occurs this is the source code generated: http://jsfiddle.net/bfed7/

Comment: Need to check what exactly we are getting in browser console. Could you please open the page in Google Chrome and let us know what you are getting in browser's console window (F12) ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured it out, tThis problem happened because the selectors in the top block were actually nested divs inside the cam-order-form. Adding

```
 $("#cam-order-form").show('slow');
 $("#cam-order-nav").hide('slow');
```

to the top if block allowed the behavior as needed because of the nesting of divs.

So another thing to be careful of when show or hide give unexpected results: Check the nesting of divs you're trying to show.